# Click event in React JS behind the scene working?

Tags: reactjs, events

I have been playing around with React Example which is on its official website:

This example really annoying me kindly helps me

**Code**

```
class LoggingButton extends React.Component {
  handleClick() {
    console.log('this is:', this);
  }

  render() {
    // This syntax ensures `this` is bound within handleClick
    return (
      <button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>             //problematic line
        Click me
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

**According to Documentation:**

> The e argument representing the React event will be passed as an
>   argument

**Problem**

I want to ask that from where this `e` comes?

I did not define `e`, then how it is working without any errors?

From where `e` is coming?

in `this.handleClick(e)`,i am passing one argument and `handleClick()` does not receive any argument then how it is working without any errors?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `e` is bound the [synthetic event](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html), which is similar to normal events you'd get when working with DOM, however this one tries to stay consistent regardless of the browser used.

This is no different from standard event handlers, which get event objects as well, with generic one [described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event). Consider a [standard DOM `click` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick).